# Typescript Parsing error: Unexpected Token Type When Importing const tuple

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, ionic-framework

I have file1 in which I have the following type definition:

```
export const repeatIntervals = [
    'never',
    'day',
    'week',
    'two weeks',
    'month',
] as const

export type RepeatInterval = typeof repeatIntervals[number]
```

In file2, I want to import `repeatIntervals` so I can use iterate over the tuple.

But I get this error during compilation `Parsing error: Unexpected token type`

Comment: Unable to reproduce this error.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @karmstr7 did you solve it? i'm facing it now